# Can we assign prototype to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React can assign prototype to child component instead of passing trough props? 
Can we do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor (){
    super()
    this.parentMethod = this.parentMethod.bind(this)
   }
   parentMethod() {
     // this method is going to be assigned to Child
     console.log('I am invoked from child')
   }

   render() {
      Child.prototype = this.parentMethod
      // now 
      return <Child />
   }

}


//Child.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class Child extends Component {
  constructor () {
     super ()
  }

   handleButton() {
      this.parentMethod()
   }
   render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.handleButton.bind(this)} > click </button>
      )
   }
}
```

I'm not very sure if I do something wrong, but the code is works?

Comment: You have a few options here - the parent can either pass the function through props to be called from the child component. Or if you have several components that may or may not be children of the parent, but still need that function - you can make a higher order component (HOC).
In short a HOC takes a component and returns a new component that has added functionality.

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-fundamentals-higher-order-components-replaces-mixins

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0):

First off, changing the `.prototype` property of an object won't set its actual prototype. The only reliable way to set an object's prototype is the [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) function. So the way you're trying to do it won't work reliably.

But even if you were doing it the right way, you really shouldn't do this anyway:

Since ES6 `class`es are just syntactic sugar over prototypes, you should *not* do this. Your React components depend on the `Component` prototype in order to ensure their lifetime methods are called at the right times and that their props are properly processed when the object is constructed. Trying to change the prototype of a React component would just mess it up and make it stop acting like a real React component.

If you want your child component to have access to its parent component's method, the right way to do this is to pass the method as a prop.

For instance:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  // React component constructors receive props
  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.parentMethod = this.parentMethod.bind(this)
   }
   parentMethod() {
     // this method is going to be assigned to Child
     console.log('I am invoked from child')
   }

   render() {
      return <Child parentCallback={this.parentMethod} />
   }

}


//Child.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class Child extends Component {
  //no constructor needed if you just call super()

   render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.props.parentCallback} > click </button>
      )
   }
}
```

Theoretically, you could have your child component `extend` your parent component, but that would be bad object-oriented design, and there are lots of nice arguments on why [you should avoid using `extends`-based inheritance](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/how-to-use-classes-and-sleep-at-night-9af8de78ccb4).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Mix-ins like here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

```
var calculatorMixin = Base => class extends Base {
  calc() { }
};

var randomizerMixin = Base => class extends Base {
  randomize() { }
};

class Foo { }
class Bar extends calculatorMixin(randomizerMixin(Foo)) { }
```